# Best practice for enabling "undelete" for database entities?

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is for a CRM application using PHP/MySQL. Various entities like customer, contact, note, etc, can be "deleted" by the user. Rather than actually deleting the entity from the database, I just want it to appear deleted to the application, but be kept in the DB and able to be "restored" if needed at a later time. Maybe even add some kind of "recycle bin" to the app.

I've thought of several ways to do this:

1. Move the deleted entity to another table. (customer to customer_deleted)
2. Change an attribute on the entity. (enabled to false)

I'm sure there are other ways and that each have their own implications on DB size, performance, etc, I'm just wondering what's the generally recommended way to do something like this?

Comment: The `customer_deleted` strategy will create lots of structural redundancy in the database. That's going to be unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go a combination of both:

1. Set a flag `deleted` to true
2. Use a cronjob to move the entries after a while to a tabelle of type `ARCHIVE`
3. If you need to restore the entry, `select into` the article table and delete from Archive

Why i would go this way?

- If a customer deleted the wrong one, the restore could be done instand
- After a few weeks/month the article table may grow up to much, so i would archive all entries that are deleted for 1 week p.a.

Comment: I wouldn't agree to moving the `article` data to another table, purely because of possible foreign key constraints and cascading operations.

Comment: @adlawson i don't see where there are cascading operations needed. If the customer want's to "undelete" an article, he have to look into the archive. If you have a table with 1000000 deleted articles, and somewhere in the table there are 100 active articles, you will get performance and storage problems. I'm sysadmin in a business/press datacenter. And thats one of the biggest problems in many CMS systems (and addressed already by the good CMS companies)

Comment: Point taken. If you're handling data where "deleted" data far outweighs that of "active" data, it may be beneficial to store in a separate table. The cascading operations I mentioned were for things like article comments or other "child" data types, where DELETE cascades are common. Joins will have to be changed and cascading operations will likely have to be moved from the db into the application, but it really depends on your specific needs.

Comment: @adlawson got your point of view too now =) Thats the reason why i would move away after a while, not instant. And if a CRM System is running a long time (and thats what they are designed for usually) you should care about that. And if the `move interval` is one year, it should be ok too on low traffic systems

Answer (score 0):

A common practice is to set a `deleted_at` column to the date at which the entity was deleted by the user (defaults to null). You may also include a `deleted_by` column for marking who deleted it. Using some kind of deleted column makes FK relationships easier to work with since these wont break. By moving the row to a new table you would have to update FK (and then update them again if you ever undelete). The downside is that you have to ensure all your queries exclude deleted rows (where this wouldnt be a problem if you moved the row to a new table). Many ORM's make this filtering easier so it depends on what you are using.

Comment: +1 Good response. I'd like to add that Doctrine 1.2 does this with it's Soft Delete behavior. Even if you're not using Doctrine 1.2, you could examine their implementation and reproduce a similar pattern.

Comment: Ha! Doctrine soft delete behavior is where I originally picked this up! They make it really easy to exclude deleted_at rows; even when you are doing joins onto a table where the foreign row is deleted. Hibernate has similar functionality for Java as well.